# Why does C++11/Boost `unordered_map` not rehash when erasing?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, unordered-map

I'm wondering why both C++11 and Boost's hashmap does not resize while erasing elements through iteration. Even if that is not technically a memory leak I think it could be a serious issue in applications (it was a hidden issue for me, had hard time to track it back) and it could actually affecting many applications. Is this a "design flaw" with the container?

I benchmarked it and seems to be affecting several compiler releases (including VS, Clang, GCC)

The code to reproduce the issue is:

```
std::unordered_map<T1,T2> m;

for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++)
        m.insert(std::make_pair(i, new data_type));


for (map_type::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end();) {
        delete it->second;
        it = m.erase(it);
}
```

I created a [self-contained test](https://github.com/Darelbi/PublicProfileTests/blob/master/BoostMemoryUsage/UnorderedMap.cpp) file that use a custom allocator to track memory usage.

As long as I understand, the reason behind that is allowing erasing elements through iteration and keep valid iterators to not erased elements.. That seems a little weird requirement since inserting elements could cause a re-hash that invalidate iterators anyway.

> But you could destroy the map directly..

Wich is how I fixed that (I wrapped the map inside a smart pointer and when it is empty I simply recreate a new empty map, resulted to be faster than rehashing, don't know why.).

In general any application that use `unordered_map` as container for caching elements could suffer from that issue (you may want to remove elements from cache but usually no one do a "cache reset")

Comment: Yep sorry. Thanks for edit

Comment: I think you correctly answered your own question.  You just disagree with the rationale.  Here's a link to the proposal which includes design rationale: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1456.html

Comment: It tells that when erasing only iterators to erased elements should be invalidated, without giving a good reason for that (seems one of the few statements that are not motivated in the whole read).. thanks for linking that.

Comment: @DarioOO It would seem little bit obvious that the reason for that be _to avoid invalidating any other iterators_. Also, if you were using `erase` as a de-facto `clear` (hoping to get a `shrink_to_size` effect), then just code it explicitly. There's value to retaining the same size even there, if the hash is repeatedly used with a population that ends up having the same kind of bucket load. Reuse is then more efficient than starting growth all over again.

Comment: Part of the reason is the same reason as why `vector` does not reallocate on erase.

Comment: `std::unordered_meow` is considered to be over-specified by some: which means that there isn't much latitude for `std` implementers to vary how it works.  As far as I can tell, a sample implementation was written, then abstract requirements based on what it does where codified...

Comment: Out of curiosity: Do you have an application, where this is a problem? Rehashing is (potentially) an expensive operation, so I'm actually glad this is the case. The only drawback I can see is that the hash table, that maps the key to a bucket, needs more space, so  you have potentially more cache misses, but on the other side you also have fewer collision.

Comment: Yes @MikeMB, a dependency injector and a small server and both suffered (the last suffered much more) from that. That was a real problem that went unnoticed for a while. I'm not saying it has to re-hash, but at least the documentation on sites like cplusplus or cppreference was lacking about mentioning such that behaviour (do you know that the self-contained test I linked in the example makes my machine lag? that's because of HUGE bandwith usage that saturate the BUS, wich could be avoided by rehashing)

Comment: Sorry, if I'm bothering you, but I'm still missing something. Ate you concerned about the memory footprint, because you have maps, that are sometimes very big (in terms of element count) but small most of the time or are you worried about performance? Because in your particular example, regular rehashing would be much slower and - at least on average - would consume more memory bandwidth.

Comment: Both ways. When these maps start to become big performance degrades too. Basically the application was lagging when it should not after some time it was running, I opened task manager and surprise almost all RAM was used, then I started a long and tedious investigation(valgrind showed none leaks) and found the problem was that, I fixed that in various ways(by rehashing manually or just dropping the map or smart ptrs), now the problem is gone but I'd liked such behaviour was well documented (I think C++ implementation could at least drop an empty bucket even if it can't do a full rehash right?)

Comment: @DarioOO: Well a bucket is effectively a linked list, so an empty bucket would consist of a single nullptr. An empty hashmap in libstdc++ requires 8 byte per bucket (on x64), so this is exactly the size of an array of nullpointers, which is the minimum you can have without rehashing. VS2015 requires two pointers per empty bucket.

Comment: The bandwith problem is that when there are few elements, but many buckets, each element force a cache miss. Bye I got great performance increase by dropping C++11 version in favor of 2 dense Maps. When One almost empty Is Just dropped and it's elements added to the other. In this way I also solved other problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, that behavior is not so much a result of the requirement to not invalidate iterators (`std::unordered_map::rehash` also doesn't invalidate them) than a result of the complexity requirement for `std::unordered_map::erase`, which should take constant time on average.

I can't tell you, why it was specified like this, but I can tell you, why it is the right default behavior **for me**:

1. In many applications, the content of my hash table is virtually
   constant after initialization anyway - so here I don't care.
2. Where this is not the case, at least the average number of elements
   stays more or less the same (within an order of magnitude).
   So even if a lot of objects are deleted at some point in time, new
   elements will probably be added soon afterwards. In that case, it
   wouldn't really reduce the memory footprint and the overhead of
   rehashing two times (once after deletion and once after adding new elements) would usually outweigh any performance improvement I might get through a more compact table.
3. Erasing a larger number of elements (e.g. by a filter function) would be severely slowed down by intermediate rehashes, if you could not control the heuristic (as you can when inserting elements by modifying `max_load_factor`).
   So finally, even in those cases where it is actually beneficial to rehash, I can usually make a better decision, about when to do it (e.g. via rehash or copy and swap) than a generic heuristic in `std::unordere_map` could.

Again, those points are true for my typical use cases, I don't claim that they are universally true for other people's software or that they were the motivation behind the specification of `unordered_map`

Interestingly, VS2015 and libstc++ seem to implement `rehash(0)` differently *:

- libstc++ will actually shrink (reallocate) the memory where the table is stored
- VS2015 will decrease the table size (a.k.a. bucket number) but not reallocate the table. So even after rehashing an empty hash map, the surplus memory for the table will not be returned.

Apparently, the only portable way to minimize the memory footprint is to copy and swap.

Concerning the documentation, I agree that this should probably be mentioned explicitly somewhere, but on the other hand it is e.g. consistent with the documentation of `std::vector::erase()`. Also I'm not 100% sure, if it is really impossible to write an implementation that rehashes on erase at least sometimes, without violating the requirements.

---

*) I inferred this from the results of `bucket_count` and `getAllocatedBytes()` from your allocator, not by actually looking at the source code.

Comment: Thanks for you time, Yes it makes perfect sense as default behaviour, seems VS2015 is somewhat buggy? The only way to free memory there is by destroying the map P_P.

Comment: @DarioOO: Well it has the advantage that it requries less dynamic meory allocations. Wether that was the right choice is certainly debatable - especially if the elements are expensive to copy.