# Does boost::unordered_multimap resize

Tags: c++, boost, hashtable

When initializing a boost::unordered_multimap, we define the size of the hash map.

```
explicit unordered_multimap(size_type n = implementation-defined, 
                            hasher const& hf = hasher(), 
                            key_equal const& eq = key_equal(), 
                            allocator_type const& a = allocator_type());

Constructs an empty container with at least n buckets, using hf as the hash function, eq as the key equality predicate, a as the allocator and a maximum load factor of 1.0.
```

When the hash map is almost full, does it resize? It does not seem having such an API. Will it do it automatically? What is the best practice of defining the size of an unordered_multimap?

Comment: Yes, it automatically resizes - it would be nearly unusable if it didn't. Best practice is to make an educated guess on the size at initialization, or let it choose its own size if that's not possible.

Comment: When does it decide to resize?

Comment: I can't say for sure without studying the code itself, but I trust that the authors chose a reasonable compromise.

Comment: @JoeC, as I understood, you refer the `n` parameter and it is a number of buckets and it is not synonym to "the size of the hash map". Moreover it is "at least" number of buckets.

Comment: And also `unordered_multimap` is now in the standard library

Comment: @megabyte1024 Then how do we control the size of a hashtable to reduce resizing. In my case, I know the total number of elements to insert in my hashtable, so if we use the default table size, for sure, resizing happens soon. I was wondering if I can 'preallocate' the table to be a bit bigger than the total elements to insert to reduce resizing times.

Answer (score 1):

It will do it automatically, [as documented](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html#idp610451568):

> The number of buckets can be automatically increased by a call to insert, or as the result of calling rehash.

But keep in mind it does not rehash when shrinking: [Why does C++11/Boost `unordered_map` not rehash when erasing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907809/why-does-c11-boost-unordered-map-not-rehash-when-erasing)

You can prevent unwanted re-hashing by manually forcing a lower load factor, and setting the maximum load factor high enough (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html#idp776321712-bb, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html#idp776318000-bb)